# I updated my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, but after forced shutdown it is not booting up

Tags: dual-boot, udev, 20.04

I updated my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, but after forced shutdown it is not booting up. Here is the Bootload screen image.

[image: Bootload screen image]

Comment: Go through the link given

Comment: same trouble for me, on a DELL latitude 5495, I should have (i think) switched off the energy saver, 'cause i launched the upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04 and when I go back black screen, laptop fan at maximum, and nothing for more than one hour. I had to force shutdown and now can't restore ancient kernel nor launch the new one! disappointed

Comment: @sol there is no direct supported update path from 19.04 to 20.04.

Comment: finally upgrade worked for me: i get back to previous install (n-2) using grub option and I did again the update by switching off the energy saver. @Bruni: experience says it seems to be doable, may be it was the point for me?

Comment: @sol I do not question that it is doable. However, it is not supported. This means that your mileage may vary, and that it is something I would never recommend on a production system. Especially if you do not have a verified backup.